# How to add/append a new row to a DataFrame in Scala without using a SQL insert?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame created in the following way.

```
val someDF = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "mouse"),(-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")
someDF.printSchema
root
 |-- number: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- word: string (nullable = true)
```

Using SQL API, one can insert a row into it by creating a temp table and running an insert query.
Is there any way one can append/add a new row using methods of the DataFrame API ?

Comment: Do you want to add a row or a column?

Comment: Sorry. It should be row. I made changes to the question.

Comment: Note: `DataFrame`s/`Dataset`s are part of what is called *"Spark SQL"*. You should say "in Spark SQL, how to [...]  without using SQL API/SQL statement"

Comment: @EnzoBnl, Sure. I will use the terms properly from here on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `union`:

```scala
val someDF = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "mouse"),(-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")
someDF.union(Seq((10, "dog")).toDF).show
/*
+------+-----+
|number| word|
+------+-----+
|     8|  bat|
|    64|mouse|
|   -27|horse|
|    10|  dog|
+------+-----+
*/
```

Comment: You can add the caveat that the column order in both the dataframes must be same. Spark doesn't warn users if the column names are in different order. It warns only if there is column type mismatch. Something to keep in mind.